# How to compare Integer with int?

Tags: java, types, nullpointerexception, int, compare

in my code, I am trying to compare an `Integer` with `int` as the condition for an `if` statement, however it returns a `NullPointerException` error. I have come across answers for the equivalence of the two, but not greater than / less than.

Here is the code I have so far: (the relevant line is `if (val > maxVal)`)

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

class Untitled {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please enter filename: ");
        Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new File(sc.nextLine()));

        int maxVal = 0;
        String maxKey = null;
        TreeMap<String,Integer> tmap = new TreeMap<String,Integer>();

        while (inFile.hasNextLine()) 
        {
            String key = inFile.nextLine();
            Integer val = tmap.get(key);
            tmap.put(key, (val==null) ? 1 : val+1);

            if (val > maxVal) {
                maxVal = val;
                maxKey = key;
            }
        }

        inFile.close();
        System.out.println(maxKey+" "+maxVal);
    }
}
```

Thanks! (I am currently learning Java and this is my first time posting on Overflow, so sorry for any errors I made).

Comment: For a [mcve], you should include example input/output. (however in this particular example it happens to be unnecessary, as the problem exists for all (non-empty) input)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest solution I see is to swap your ternary to the assignment of `val` (and you might as well use `int`). Also, I would *prefer* [`Map.getOrDefault(Object, V)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#getOrDefault-java.lang.Object-V-).  Like,

```
int val = 1 + tmap.getOrDefault(key, 0);
tmap.put(key, val);
if (val > maxVal) {
    maxVal = val;
    maxKey = key;
}
```

Otherwise, you could *repeat* the ternary in your comparison (but I personally think that's ugly so I'll leave it as a completely optional exercise for the reader).

Comment: Thanks!! That fixed it! If you don't mind clarifying, how is `1 + tmap.getOrDefault(key, 0)` able to replace the ternary? I read the Docs about .getOrDefault` but couldn't really understand it.

Comment: @RichardRobinson The value you want is one plus the existing value (which is zero if the value doesn't exist in the map). Your ternary is the same (logically). You could also have written `Integer val = tmap.containsKey(key) ? 1 + tmap.get(key) : 1;` - there are many ways to *express* things.

Answer (score 0):

It is giving you a `NullPointerException` because the value you are comparing is null (the value you are getting from your map is null), not because of a comparison between `int` and `Integer`.

The first time through your loop the map is empty, so your call to get will return null.  Then you are attempting to check whether `val` (which is null) is less than `maxVal`.  You are immediately inserting a 1 if `val` is null, but your subsequent comparison is not guarding against `val` being null.

---

The Map `get()` method also returns null if the key is not found,

- [Map (Java Platform SE 8 ) - get](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#get-java.lang.Object-)

Comment: "_It is **not** giving you a NullPointerException..._" what are you talking about? The OP states that it gives a `NullPointerException`, "_however it returns a NullPointerException..._"

Comment: You didn't read the whole sentence.  I said "It is not giving you a NullPointerException because of a comparison between int and Integer, but because the value you are comparing is null."  I never said it wasn't giving a NullPointerException.  The OP seemed to imply that the NPE may be coming from comparing an int with and Integer, and that is not the case.

Comment: Sorry your answer was quite unclear to me. Removed the downvote. :)